# Can I use C sockets without including <sys/socket.h>?

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I'm developing a simple C++ program and would like to use C sockets. Is it possible to use them by declaring inside extern "C" rather than including the <sys/socket.h>?

We can use extern "C" to declare libc bindings such as write:

```cpp
extern "C" {
    int write(int fd, const char *buf, int count);
};
```

However, when declaring the required socket functions the results are unreliable. What I found is that I can create sockets and set options, however connect() always times out.

Here is an example of using pure extern "C" declarations

```
gcc extern.cpp -o extern ; ./extern
```

```cpp
extern "C" {
    struct  hostent {
        char *  h_name;
        char ** h_aliases;
        int     h_addrtype;
        int     h_length;
        char ** h_addr_list;
    };
    #define h_addr  h_addr_list[0]
    struct in_addr {
        unsigned long s_addr;
    };
    struct sockaddr {
        unsigned short  sa_family;
        char            sa_data[14];
    };
    struct sockaddr_in {
        short            sin_family;
        unsigned short   sin_port;
        struct in_addr   sin_addr;
        char             sin_zero[8];
    };
    void* memset(void*, int, long unsigned int);
    void* memcpy(void*, const void*, long unsigned int);
    int write(int, const char*, int);
    int close(int);
    hostent* gethostbyname(const char*);
    int socket(int, int, int);
    int connect(int, sockaddr*, int);
    int send(int, const char*, int, int);
    int recv(int, char*, int, int);
    int getsockopt(int, int, int, void*, unsigned int*);
    int setsockopt(int, int, int, const void*, unsigned int);
    unsigned short htons(unsigned short);
    void perror(const char*);
    void exit(int);
    #define AF_INET 2
    #define SOCK_STREAM 1
    #define TCP_NODELAY 1
    #define TCP_SYNCNT  7
    #define IPPROTO_TCP 6
};

void error(const char *s) {
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main() {
    hostent *hp;
    int nodelay = 1;
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
        error("socket");
    }
    setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (const char *)&nodelay, sizeof(int));

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    if((hp = gethostbyname("stackoverflow.com")) == 0) {
        error("gethostbyname");
    }
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);

    // Reduce sock timeout
    int synRetries = 2;
    setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_SYNCNT, &synRetries, sizeof(synRetries));

    // When using extern "C" this seems to timeout
    if (connect(sockfd, (sockaddr*)(&serv_addr), sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0) {
        close(sockfd);
        error("connect");
    }

    send(sockfd, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n\0", 19, 0);
    char buf[1024];
    recv(sockfd, buf, 1024, 0);
    write(0, buf, 1024);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the connect() function to resolve; however, unless I include `<sys/socket.h>` connect() will timeout.

Is there any way around this, I am interested to see if it is possible to work with sockets using pure extern "C".

Comment: You can include the `#include` inside of `extern "C" { ... }`

Comment: In principle, yes, you can declare all the needed functions and constants directly, the former with C linkage, instead of including `sys/socket.h`, but why do so?  It is both safer and easier to use the header (more than one, actually, to cover all the functions you list).  Put its inclusion in an `extern "C"` block.

Comment: Where did you get `int connect(int, sockaddr*, int);` from? That doesn't match the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/connect.html) at all. Why would you expect that to work?

Comment: The [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), which defines the (minimum) contents of `sys/socket.h`, explicitly says that it is OK to include this header (and all of the other headers it defines) from C++.  So you don't _need_ to do this.  Why do you want to?

Comment: @zwol: exercise in preparation for making a binding library for another language perhaps? It's something he should be able to do.

Comment: Joshua is correct. It's interesting to strip the language back to raw symbols and use them directly. Getting this working is part of the exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have gotten an IPv6 address back from gethostbyname and wrote it to sockaddr, overflowing the buffer and trashing stuff. You then tried to connect to the lead part of the IPv6 address as an IPv4 address and that IP doesn't want to talk to you.

Also this line is nuts but I can't see why this would fail it:

memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr))

Should be

memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr))